# Speeding up DBCC CHECKDB on a large database

Tags: sql-server, performance, dbcc-checkdb

I have 16 GB RAM, 12 GB allocated for SQL Server, total size of all databases on an instance 5TB.

`DBCC CheckDB with PhysicalOnly` checking on the biggest database ~ 3TB.

1 socket, 2 virtual processors.

Takes more than 20 hr to run, which is affecting users.

It is a test server, so *tempdb* is on the same drive along with data and log files.

Is any way to speed it up, or do I really need to add RAM?

Here are the read/write latencies:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface) suggested:

> Backup/restore to somewhere else and run `CHECKDB` there.
>
> Two vCPUs and 16GB RAM for a 5TB instance seems rather undersized, but upgrading your storage speed is probably the first priority, can you get SSDs?

See also:

- [Minimizing the impact of DBCC CHECKDB : DOs and DON'Ts](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/io-subsystem/minimize-impact-of-checkdb) by Aaron Bertrand.
- [A faster CHECKDB](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/a-faster-checkdb-8211-part-i/ba-p/316769) by Bob Ward of Microsoft.
- [3 Ways to Run DBCC CHECKDB Faster](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/08/3-ways-to-run-dbcc-checkdb-faster/) by Brent Ozar.